# Is there a way to create a select list with a default value, but no drop down

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Bit of a strange question really,  but is there a way to create an select option list that display the text 'select one' but when you click it it actually doesn't drop down?

The reason, I have encapsulated all the options within a display created from div tags that displays correctly given the size of the content and the display area on the page.  I want to use the select box with the drop down arrow as they trigger but don't want it to do anything else.

These are .asp pages.  The css on the top level  tag allows me to set a width, however I would like to be able to set the width on the  tags to be wider, big titles for categories but unfortunately this does not work.  But I want to use a drop down box initially so that initially it looks like a standard box as the styling for such items is browser specific.

Thanks

Comment: I did say it was a strange question!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/SEen2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/SEen2/

JavaScript

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('div.options').show();
});​
```

HTML

```
<button type="button">
    <select>
        <option>Select One</option>
    </select>
    <div></div>
</button>

<div class="options" style="display: none;"> some other option window. </div>​
```

CSS

```
button {
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;    
}
button div { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;  
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

​
So a crazy solution to a crazy question. The select wrapped in the button just gives me a clickable area. The button could just as easily have been a div wrapper but whatever. The div in the button is on top of the select to prevent any clicks on the select.

The jQuery is simple enough to understand.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly in IE, it doesn't look like a select list anymore!  But it has given me some ideas and for that I am very appreciative.  Thanks.